# C - passing struct pointer terminates the program? How to

Tags: c, pointers, struct

My problem is the initialisePlayer() always makes program crashed when I execute it

Comment: Don't post text as images!

Comment: And where do you allocate memory for the `Player` structure? All you seem to have is a null pointer.

Comment: You need to allocate space for player

Comment: I see a lot of code, I even see a picture I won't use because I won't copy its content in my text editor, but I see no MVCE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass player as the address of player to the initialize function:

```
    initialisePlayer(&player, &pos, direction);
```

and allocate memory for it in initialize:

```
void initialisePlayer(Player **player, Position * position, Direction direction);
{
    Player *p= malloc(sizeof(Player));
    p->position.x = position->x;
    p->position.y = position->y;
    p->direction = direction;
    p->moves = 0;
    *player= p;
}
```

Comment: then how to pass 'player' to the displayBoard(..) function? thank you!

Comment: Just as you do now. Only Player has now been initialized!

Comment: ohh it works for me now, thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Then give an upvote.